# How can I load a specified Animator from StateListAnimator xml file programatically?

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to programatically load specified animator class from StateListAnimator defined on xml file so that I can add listener to it programatically?

I know we can do that with simple Animator xml file, but not for any xml that represents StateListAnimator. I have tried applying ID to the animator class on xml but it seems we can't apply any IDs to it.

Below is my code to load state list animator from xml and the content of xml file.

Thanks in advance!

On API level 21 or above:

```
AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(
    getContext(), R.animator.state_list_animator);
```

Below is my state_list_animator xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                            android:propertyName="rotation"
                            android:valueTo="0f"
                            android:valueType="floatType"
                    />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                            android:propertyName="rotation"
                            android:valueTo="180f"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Comment: oh.. so all I can do is just define and write all of those animator codes on my Activity / Fragment then... ;(

Comment: but..., you can load `Animator` from xml and then call `addState(int[] specs, Animator animator)`

Comment: That's true; I'll give up what I wanted for now and do that way instead. I hope I can do that someday in the future though.. anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: Hey pskink, can you write again or copy&paste what you have wrote as an answer? I will just close this question as your answer is already fulfilling and I'm guessing there is no other comment or answers coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you cannot do that...

but..., you can load `Animator` from xml and then call `StateListAnimator#addState(int[] specs, Animator animator)`

Comment: okay. I'll give up what I wanted for now and do that way instead. I hope I can do that someday in the future though.. anyway, thanks! :)